# Online Hackathon prize money taxation and exceptions

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, foreign-income

I've participated in one of the Hackathon competition on [DevPost](https://devpost.com/) and won the prize amount of $3000 USD.

However, the claiming section asked me to fill-up the [W-8BEN tax form](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw8ben.pdf) as I'm not a US resident. The form has a field for income type, but not sure about few things.

1. What should need to be filled in income type?
2. It is not a lucky draw or kind of gambling though, will I have to pay tax to the US government?
3. Is there any chance to claim 0% taxes from the US government? or another exception?
4. What will be the final amount I will receive on-hand?

*Other note:* 
I individually won the award, there is no other team member to share this amount with.

Comment: My guess is that this is "Other Income" in the sense of the [1989 US–India income tax treaty](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/india-tax-treaty-documents). Such Other Income is taxable only in the country of residence. This is definitely not a royalty.

Comment: @amon, Thanks! I have read that pinned document. Can't it be fall under Article 15?    *The term “professional services” includes independent scientific, literary, artistic, educational or
teaching activities as well as the independent activities of physicians, surgeons, lawyers, engineers,
architects, dentists and accountants.*

Comment: You could claim to have provided *hacking* services, I suppose, but when people are paid for their services, they don’t usually consider the payment to be prize money.

Comment: You didn't provide a service. You didn't negotiate a price for your work. If your job had been fry cook and you won the hackathon there wouldn't be a difference.

Comment: @xyious: so what do you think I should need to mention in income type?

Comment: What are the options ? It's not a royalty. It's prize money, same as if you won the US open :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone facing the same issue, here is the tip. Fill out **Part I**, **Part II (9)** and **part III**

**Leave the Part II (10) blank** and submit. You'll get your full amount.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the update I also won $2000 and was wondering how to avoid tax, would it be the same for an African country?

Comment: Congratulations! perhaps the same for all non US residents. However, it also depends on an agreement between two countries. @Harry

Comment: Hey, so for India this works? Also, do you have any idea on what other countries this works for?

Comment: @Harry were you able to avoid it, if so how did you do it?

Comment: @KarunShrestha No way of avoiding the 30% tax in Africa